# More confusion over SEO Cname and 301 redirect

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, cname

Previous answers on this topic don't really help me with my query, so any help appreciated for a bit of a newbie.

I have a new domain  "domain#1.mobi"  Its hosted with godaddy and has a cname and forwarding, pointing it to "domain#1.elsewhere.us" 
It has no content.

The content is all hosted on "domain#1.elsewhere.us"  which is what Google is now listing in its results.

I want Google to ignore that and only list "domain#1.mobi" in its listings.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If your mobi domain is forwarded that explains why Google is indexing your .us domain. If you want your mobi domain to be indexed stop forwarding it and add content to it along with a sitemap and submit that to Google webmaster center

Comment: Thanks, but because of the way the site is created and hosted the .US is the only one which can have the content.  The .mobi is just a domain name to give my client a  simpler and more memorable URL.

Comment: Remove the CNAME and only forward the mobi domain then you will not have a problem with Google. Google will only index your .us domain, the CNAME is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you managed to focus Google on .mobi?